# Using google's api to list result of search

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey i want to list the results from a google search, i saw that you can query google's api by using urls like this one

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Earth%Day
```

In the asp.net framework i have no idea how to query this url without exiting the page. I know Response.Redirect(myquery); would work but it makes the browser leave the current page, how do i get the JSON result from that query without leaving the page ?

Thanks !

ps: I did do alot of searches before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes in the .Net Framework:

```
var request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Earth%Day");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseText = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx